# Can't prove $2^n > n$ with Mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, provability

As the title states, I have a problem with proving $2^n > n$

I can do the basis step fine:
Basis step:

```
"n = 1"

2^1 = 2
2 > 1
```

So it is true for $n$.

But then I get stuck with the inductive step. Here's how I tried, but then I get stuck. I don't know what to do.

```
Inductive step:
"Assume true for n"
"Prove for n+1"

  2^(n+1) > n+1

= 2^1 * 2^n
= 2*2^n
= 1*2^n + 2^n
= 2^n + 2^n > n+1
```

If you know the answer, please explain it to me so I know how to do it in the future. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$, we have $2^1=2>n=1$.  Now, assume that for some $k>1$ we have

$$2^k>k \tag 1$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
2^{k+1}&=2(2^k) \tag 2\\\\
&>2(k) \tag 3\\\\
&=k+k \tag 4\\\\
&>k+1 \tag 5
\end{align}$$

for $k>1$.

> Notes:
>
> In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used the assumption $2^k>k$ as given in $(1)$.
>
> Then, in arriving at $(4)$, we simply used the fact that $2k=k+k$.

Finally, since $k>1$, $k+k>k+1$.

Therefore, by the principal of mathematical induction, $2^n>n$ for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry could you break that big part up for me? It'd help to have it explained in English. Maybe, if you don't mind, explain why you're doing each step and how it's possible.

Comment: Sure.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand step 3. Where is 2(k) coming from? What is it and where is it coming from?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And $2^{k+1}=2\times 2^k$.  Then, recall from $(1)$ that we assumed that $2^k>k$.

Comment: Yes, but is Step 3 trying to say that we're transforming k+1 into 2(k)? I don't understand how or why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

If $n = 1$, then $2^{n} = 2 > n = 1$; if $n \geq 1$ is such that $2^{n} > n$, then $2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^{n} > 2n \geq n+1$; hence by mathematical induction we are done.